# Corrupt Excel File

Tags: excel

I have a user who was working on an Excel 2007 file from a thumbdrive.. all of a suddem the file will not open and generates the following error:

"Excel cannot open the file 'filename.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file. (OK)"

I hit Ctrl-Shift-i to get the code for that error (101590)

Any ideas how to repair?

I have tried the following to no avail:

- Open and Repair tool
- Opening with OpenOffice
- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/repairing-a-corrupted-workbook-HA010097017.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to rename file. Go to tools, folder options, file types and check have you .xlsx extension. If not then rename the file .xlsx to .xls

Second try to look here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4994c2f4-ce6e-467d-a06c-d9ab7d67b706/i-have-a-case-that-the-client-work-on-an-exists-excel-file?forum=excel

Comment: XLSX is present in File Types. Still XLSX file is not opening which I renamed from .CSV is not opening. This was working before and suddenly this problem started occurring from last 2 weeks. We have not done any patch or updates on the system. Using Office 2013. Please can anybody help how to resolve the issue. We only have to use .XLSX. We cannot use .XLS due to business limitations.